# Python program send FIX message to server doesn't work

Tags: python, sockets, fix-protocol

I am now working on a project to transfer FIX message to a server and get response. The thing is that I think I successfully sent a Test Request but I got no response. Also, from the server side, the guy told me that the message I sent was messed up.

The following is my code, hope someone can help me get out of this. Thanks in advance. As this is just a test, the message is hardcoded.

```
import socket
from time import sleep
import sys
SOH = chr(1)

def checksum(str):
    res = 0
    for i in xrange(len(str)):
        res += ord(str[i])
    return res % 256

def client():
    bodylength = len('35=1' + SOH + '49=IDMYSIDE' + SOH + '56=IDSERVER' + SOH + '34=1' + SOH + '52=20170425-12:50:32' + SOH + '112=123' + SOH)
    packet = '8=FIX.4.2' + SOH + '9=' + str(bodylength) + SOH + '35=1' + SOH + '49=IDMYSIDE' + SOH + '56=IDSERVER' + SOH + '34=1' + SOH + '52=20170425-12:50:32' +  SOH + '112=123' + SOH
    sums = str(checksum(packet))
    sums = '0'*(3-len(sums)) + sums
    packet = packet + '10=' + sums + SOH
    print packet
    HOST, PORT = 'xx.xx.xx.x', 1000    
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    bytessend = sock.sendall(packet)
    print bytessend
    # I reveive nothig here
    sleep(3)
    reply = sock.recv(2560)
    print "recvd: ", reply

client()
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to help if the only description of the error is that the message "was messed up." You'll need to provide some specifics

Comment: BTW, your checksum function could be rewritten `return sum(ord(c) for c in string) % 256`

Comment: @brianpck  according to the guy in server side, he said that what i am doing is to re-establish a TCP/IP connection and he actually did not get anything from my side. I wonder what happens in this case. BTW, thanks for the advice in calculating checksum!